# Number range on an edittext - only want numbers between 1 and 10

Tags: android, button, onclick, range

I'm trying to make an app that only allows a user to enter between 1 and 10, I've tried writing my own method where if the number is out of that range, it changes the text views to ERROR and clears what's in the edit text, however it crashes the app. Does anyone know what's wrong with it? New to android.

Code:

```
    public void buttonClick (View v)
{



    TextView tvNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNumEnt);
    TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNumEnt);
    TextView tvNameEnt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NameEnt);
    TextView tvNumEnt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NumEnt);

    EditText num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETnumber);
    EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETname);

    String nameContent = name.getText().toString();
    String numContent = num.getText().toString();

    tvName.setText(nameContent);

        int value = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
        if (value > 10)
        {
            tvNum.setText("ERROR");
            num.getText().clear();
            name.getText().clear();

        }
        else if (value < 1)
        {
            tvNum.setText("ERROR");
            num.getText().clear();
            name.getText().clear();
        }
        else
        {



            tvNum.setText(numContent);

            tvNameEnt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNumEnt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNum.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue on this line

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(num.toString());
```

change to:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
```

Now you call `toString()` method from `Object` for `EditText` object. You have to call `getText()` method for it as first and after then call `toString()` method for `CharSequence`

UPDATE:
You find two times the same view with the same ids. Look at the code below:

```
TextView tvNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNumEnt);
TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNumEnt);
```

there should be `R.id.tvNumEnt` in the second time, I think so...

```
TextView tvNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNumEnt);
TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNumEnt);
```

Comment: Thankyou - will pick this answer - I've updated my code above and it works now, however it doesn't seem to change tvName to what is typed in, i've tried it in and out of the if statements and can't figure out why it's not changing it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any idea on this problem? :)

Comment: On more think you two times set the same text view
 TextView tvNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNumEnt);
    TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNumEnt); here is two times the same id

Comment: @MikeHunt let see my update, maybe it will be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you are trying to get the number in the edittext with: `num.toString()`, instead you have to use: `num.getText().toString()`